# JavaScript for drag and drop img not working on Ipad / Iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad

New preoblem! I need to get this working on Ipad / Iphone

Internet Explorer issue SOLVED!

Changed ev.dataTransfer.setData("content",ev.target.id); to ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);

I'm curently working on a web education where one part is a drag and drop query.
It's works just fine in Chrome and Firefox but it won't work in Explorer.
I'm new to JS and not so familar to what MS "standards" difrences is.
Excuse if my english is bad but it's not my native language.

JS code:

```
var i = 0;

function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("content",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var image =ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");

  if (ev.target.id == document.getElementById(image).getAttribute('data-div'))
  { 
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
    i++;

if(i == 9)
{
    document.getElementById('next').style.display="inline";
}
  }
  else
  {
     alert("Wrong");
  }
}
```

Html code:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="drop" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div class="drop" id="div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>

<div id="pic">
    <img class="drag" id="drag1" data-div="div1" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag2" data-div="div2" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag3"  data-div="div3" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag4"  data-div="div4" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag5"  data-div="div5" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag6"  data-div="div6" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag7"  data-div="div7" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag8"  data-div="div8" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img class="drag" id="drag9"  data-div="div9" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
</div>

<div id="next"> 
    <a href="q2.php" target="content"> Nästa </a>
</div>
```

I use this JS code in some other files for Explorer issues:

```
var CB = 
{
addEvent : function(element, event, action)
{
    if (element.addEventListener)
    {
        element.addEventListener(event, action, false);
    }
    else
    {
        element.attachEvent("on" + event, action);
    }
}
}
```

Very thankful for help

//Emil

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you using? What error are you getting if you use the IE developer tools to debug it?

Comment: I use IE 11 and I get an error on ev.dataTransfer.setData("content",ev.target.id);

Comment: What error message are you getting? I'm referring to the message in white on red that appears below the line of code that fails.

Comment: The error msg says "{exception} An unexpected call was made to gain access to methods or properties."

Answer (score 1):

IE does not send the events through a function parameter, but as a part of the `window` object. Because you call your event parameter `ev`, it does not know that this is actually `event`.

If you want to use the event in IE, you'll have to write the following line as the first line of code for every window (in your case):

```
ev = ev || window.event;
```

or you can just replace every instance of `ev` in your code with `event`, because the window parameter can be used implicitly.

source: http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Comment: After alot of Googeling i found an out this: change ev.dataTransfer.setData("content",ev.target.id); to ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);

Comment: Thanks for your time i really appraiset it!